# issues when retrieving XML attributes with namespaces with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Basically, I've got an XML like this :

```
<com:myObject xmlns="myNamespaceUrl" xmlns:ref="myUrl/reference" xmlns:type="myUrl/type" xmlns:com="myUrl/common">
   <com:myNode help="12" ref:label="myLabel" type:cen="true">text</com:myNode
</com:myObjet>
```

When I try to get value for the node:

```
"com:myObject/@help"
```

I've got "12".

But my problem is when I try to get value for nodes:

`"com:myObjet/@ref:label"` or `"com:myObject/@type:cen"`

I've got no result. So I believe it comes from the namespace, but I'm not sure. I've declared the namespaces in my XSL file also.

I use the *jaxp-api.1.4.2 plugin.*

Answer (score 1):

```
com:myObjet/@ref:label
```

and

```
com:myObject/@type:cen
```

return nothing because myObject does not have those attributes. They belong to myNode.

```
//com:myNode/@ref:label
```

returns the expected value. Note that xpaths are evaluated in context, so depending on where you execute the xpath from you may need to include the leading `//`.